# Howto put advertising as post number 1,2,3 etc

Tags: posts

I would like to put advertising as post number 1,or 2 or 3,etc ( I can pick any number basicly).

Anyone know how to do it?

So basicly just like post number 1 is normal standard post and then post number 2 is advertising (banner ads,adsense), and then post number 3 is just normal standard post again,etc

Help please

UPDATE: My current loop code is:

```
<section class="home-section format-posts">

<?php if( get_sub_field( 'format_main_title' ) ): ?>
<header class="section-header">
    <h2 class="title"><span><?php the_sub_field( 'format_main_title' ); ?></span></h2>
    <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'format_sub_title' ) ): ?>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_sub_field( 'format_sub_title' ); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</header>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
/**
 * Get the format name which will filter the section
 * Check if format is standard or something else
**/
$format_name = get_sub_field( 'format_section_name' );

if ( get_sub_field( 'format_section_name' ) == 'standard' ):
    $format_args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' =>  array( 'post-format-video', 'post-format-gallery', 'post-format-audio' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
else:
    $format_args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-'.$format_name
        );
endif;

$posts_to_show = get_sub_field( 'format_posts_per_page' );

if ( get_sub_field ( 'format_pagination' ) == 'pagination_on' ){

    $paged = 1;
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

    $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_show,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' => array( $format_args )
        )
    );
} else {
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_to_show,
            'tax_query' => array( $format_args )
        )
    );
}

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>

    <div class="grids masonry-layout entries">

    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>        
            <article <?php post_class("grid-4"); ?>>

                <figure class="entry-image">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-size' );
                    } elseif( first_post_image() ) { // Set the first image from the editor
                        echo '<img src="' . first_post_image() . '" class="wp-post-image" />';
                    } ?>
                    </a>

                    <?php
                    // Add icon to different post formats
                    if ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() ): // Gallery
                        echo '<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i>';
                    elseif ( 'video' == get_post_format() ): // Video
                        echo '<i class="icon-camera"></i>';
                    elseif ( 'audio' == get_post_format() ): // Audio
                        echo '<i class="icon-music"></i>';
                    endif;
                    ?>

                </figure>

                <header class="entry-header">
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                       <span class="entry-date"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="entry-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <?php if( $ti_option['site_author_name'] == 1 ) { ?>
                    <span class="entry-author">
                        <?php _e( 'By','themetext' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" rel="author"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></a>
                    </span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </header>

                <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'format_excerpt' ) == 'enable' ) { ?>
                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> uu
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

    <?php 
    if ( get_sub_field ( 'format_pagination' ) == 'pagination_on' ){ // Enable/Disable the pagination
        ti_pagination();
    } 
    ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="grids entries">
        <p class="grid-12 message">
            <?php _e( 'There are no posts with this format yet', 'themetext' ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property of `WP_Query`:

> $current_post
>
> (available during The Loop) Index of the post currently being displayed.

Let's say you have your current version of loop:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    ... some code that is displaying current post
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Change it to something like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <?php global $wp_query; if ($wp_query->current_post == 2): ?>
    ... put advert here
    <?php else: ?>
    ... some code that is displaying current post
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can, of course, change this condition: `($wp_query->current_post == 2)` to anything you like.

So in your case it should look like this:

```
<?php
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            $wp_query->the_post();
            if ( $wp_query->current_post == 2 ) {
                // put your advert here
            } else
                get_template_part( 'content', 'post' );
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Update your question and insert this code inside your question, pls. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: Btw still need your help please and thank you very much in advance ( I am sorry I am just newbie)

Comment: I updated again my current loop if you notice that

Comment: anyone help please

Comment: But what is your problem now? What is your question? You change your loop and want us to write everything for you? Have you even tried to do anything with this answer? I've tried to explain it very clearly. If you have questions - ask. If you want me to do it for you, sorry - not this kind of site, I guess...